# Histogram with density fit and bars labeled with frequency

Tags: r, histogram, probability, frequency

I would like to show the probability for the histogram, with a density curve fit, and with the bars labeled by the count.  The code below generates two figures, the top shows the frequency bars (labeled by frequency) with the density curve.  The bottom shows the probability bars (labeled by probability) with the density curve.  What I would like to have is the probability bars labeled by frequency, so we can read probability and frequency.  Or, I would like to have the second plot, with the bar labels from the first plot.

```
coeff_value = c(6.32957806, 3.04396650, 0.02487562, 3.50699592, 5.03952569, 3.05907173, 
0.41095890, 1.88648325, 5.04250569, 0.89320388, 0.83732057, 1.12033195, 
2.35697101, 0.58695652, 4.83363583, 7.91154791, 7.99614644, 9.58737864, 
1.27358491, 1.03938247, 8.66028708, 6.32458234, 3.85263158, 1.37299546, 
0.53639847, 7.63614043, 0.51502146, 9.86557280, 0.60728745, 3.00613232, 
6.46573393, 2.60848869, 2.34273319, 1.82448037, 6.36600884, 0.70043777, 
1.47600793, 0.42510121, 2.58064516, 3.45377741, 6.29475205, 4.97536946, 
2.24637681, 2.12000000, 1.92792793, 0.97613883, 6.01214190, 4.47316103, 
1.87272727, 10.08896797, 0.09049774, 1.93779904, 6.53444676, 3.46590909, 
6.52730822, 7.23229671, 4.91740279, 5.24545125)
h=hist(coeff_value,plot=F,freq=T,breaks=10)
h$density = h$density*100
par(mfrow=c(2,1)) 
plt=plot(h, freq=T, main="Freq = T",xlab="rate", 
       ylab="Frequency", xlim=c(0, 20), ylim=c(0, 30),
       col="gray", labels = TRUE)
densF=density(coeff_value)
lines(densF$x, densF$y*length(coeff_value), lwd=2, col='green') 
plt=plot(h, freq=F, main="Freq = F",xlab="rate", 
       ylab="Probability (%)", xlim=c(0, 20), ylim=c(0, 30),
       col="gray", labels = TRUE)
densF=density(coeff_value)
lines(densF$x, densF$y*100, lwd=2, col='green') 

paste("bar sum =",sum(h$density))
paste("line integral =",sum((densF$y[-length(densF$y)]*100)*diff(densF$x)))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just plot your histogram and capture the output (you'll still need to multiply the density by 100 to get to % before plotting):

```
h <- hist(coeff_value,plot=F,breaks=10)
h$density <- h$density*100
plot(h, freq=F, xlab="rate", 
       ylab="Probability (%)", ylim=c(0, 25),
       col="gray")
densF <- density(coeff_value)
lines(densF$x, densF$y*100, lwd=2, col='green')
```

Now `h` contains all the information you need:

```
text(h$mids,h$density,h$counts,pos=3)
```

[image: histogram with density and counts]

Comment: I still want the density in percent.

Comment: Is it also possible to somehow smooth the line so that it looks more like a distribution?

Comment: @Anonymosaurus: the green line is a density (up to scaling). If you have a specific question, it might be better to create a new post.